# Unexpected End of File

Tags: c, makefile, bison

I download iasl 20190509 version in Ubunt18.04.5 LTS.
When I use "make iasl" command to build the package, I get this error:

```
$ make iasl 
make[1]: Entering directory 'acpica-unix2-20190509/generate/unix/iasl'
- bison obj/aslcompiler.y
acpica-unix2-20190509/generate/unix/iasl/obj/aslcompiler.y:1.1: error: syntax error, unexpected end of file
mv: cannot stat 'obj/AslCompiler.LLW4kB/y.tab.h': No such file or directory
Makefile:322: recipe for target 'obj/aslcompiler.y.h' failed
make[1]: *** [obj/aslcompiler.y.h] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory 'acpica-unix2-20190509/generate/unix/iasl'
generate/unix/Makefile.common:7: recipe for target 'iasl' failed
make: *** [iasl] Error 2
```

Please help me fix this error.

Please help me build iasl.

Comment:  Please post code, errors, sample data or textual output here as plain-text, not as images that can be hard to read, can’t be copy-pasted to help test code or use in answers, and are barrier to those who depend on screen readers or translation tools. You can edit your question to add the code in the body of your question. For easy formatting use the `{}` button to mark blocks of code, or indent with four spaces for the same effect. The contents of a **screenshot can’t be searched, run as code, or easily copied and edited to create a solution.**

Comment: "STL" meaning "LTS"?

Comment: Yes, sorry I input error

Comment: It looks as though the grammar file is empty (that's the error you get from Bison if you run it on an empty file — or `/dev/null`).  You need to look at the downloaded code to see whether the grammar file got clobbered somewhere along the line.

Comment: Dima: please do `make clean` and then `make` and show all the errors, not just the last one. Thanks. @jonathan: `aslcompiler.y` is generated earlier in the build using `m4`. If that step failed, it might have left an empty file as a byproduct.

Comment: @rici thank you for your help. I built iasl success.

Comment: Thanks, @rici: I'd not actually looked at the code — one of a number of reasons I didn't post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to retry the `make` but making sure that the build directory is clean first:

```bash
$ make clean && make
```

Here's my best guess as to what happened:

1. An attempt was made to build the software package.
2. That attempt failed because the `m4` tool had not previously been installed.
3. OP installed m4, and reran the build with `make`.
4. Because of an inadequacy in the provided `Makefile`, `make` did not attempt to run `m4` again. (See below.) Consequently, processing of the file supposedly generated by `m4` failed.

This software package relies on `m4` to create the source for `bison` by interpolating various component files. (Yacc/Bison doesn't have an `include` feature, so `m4` is the usual solution.) However, the command to run `m4` is roughly (with paths simplified):

```bash
$ m4 aslparser.y > aslcompiler.y
```

When the shell executes this command, it creates or truncates `aslcompiler.y`
before even attempting to invoke `m4`. If it turns out that `m4` can't be found, or if `m4` produces some sort of error, you end up with an empty or partial output file.

The `make` target `aslcompiler.y` is satisfied by this artefact, since `make` only cares that the target was created later than its dependencies. So the next invocation of `make` goes on to the next step (`bison aslcompiler.y`), which fails because `aslcompiler.y` is empty.

The `Makefile` would have been better written to use a command like:

```bash
$ m4 aslparser.y > /tmp/aslcompiler.y && mv /tmp/aslcompiler.y aslcompiler.y
```

in order to avoid creating the target if `m4` failed. Of course, that's not your responsibility. It could be reported as a bug to the iASL project. (The `Makefile` already uses this strategy to safely handle the files generated by Bison, so it's not really anything new.)